# Stop DHCP Reservation Name from being Overwritten

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp

Two part question here.

1. For what purpose are the names of my DHCP reservations being overwritten?
2. How can I stop it from happening? We use Win 2K3 Ent. Server and associated services, ie: DNS, DHCP, AD.

Comment: Can you explain your problem in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Reservations serve to associate a mac with an IP address. I believe that DHCP reservations always (at least by default - I've never thought to change this behavior) assume the name of the client, if the client provides a name.

Why do you need to prevent updates to it?

Could you instead use the description field of the reservation?

Comment: I use the name field as a visual reminder of what device holds the reservation. The reason is that the name field is visible in the list you are presented inside the MMC. That I know of you can't add the description field to the MMC view.

Answer (score 1):

The devices which take the reservations hold netbios/wins/dns machine names on the network. It's these machine names which are being checked by the DHCP server and, where it doesn't match the name you entered, the dhcp server is updating its entry to reflect the machine name.

To correct the behavior, ensure the devices in question are communicating on the network with the correct network name.

Comment: In the case of my BMCs on my IBM servers I'm not sure I can change its network name. There are other devices that applies to as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know someone would need to do that manually.

Comment: That's the issue. I manually set the reservation name when I create it. It, at some point, is being changed by a process.